# Scaling and overlapping ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am a bit of an android noob, and have been struggling with this problem for far too long.

**What I'm aiming for:** 
Two `ImageViews`. The first will be the width of the screen, and drawn to match the proportions of its src image (so far so easy). The second `ImageView` needs to be scaled, so that its width is a fixed multiple (between 0 and 1) of the first image. 
I will ultimately then need to be able to touch-drag the second smaller image around on top of the first, fixed image, although this part is not the point of this question.

This will all generally be done programmatically, as the src images and the scale multiple are not known until runtime.

**What I've tried:** I can overlay two `ImageViews` in a `RelativeLayout`, using `alignParentTop` and so on. This works fine, but I can't see how to scale the images in this case.

I can alternatively scale the two `ImageViews` using a `LinearLayout`, by setting their `layout_weights` to 1 and the scale multiple respectively. In this case I can't get the images overlapping however (not strictly true - I have managed this with negative margins, but it is a very hacky solution and will make it almost impossible to implement the movement of the top image later).

So my question is: is there a way to fix either of the two solutions I have tried to implement? Or is there perhaps a better way to approach the problem? 
(I'm not necessarily looking for an answer in code, just the approach I should take)

Answer (score 0):

Well with what I understand,

You can use a Constraint Layout

Place 1st ImageView on your desired place
with constraints to your parent

Place Second ImageView on your desired place
with constraints to the parent (NOT WITH ANY OTHER CHILD VIEW)
The Approach is if you put a SubView In ConstraintLayout with Constraints to Parent, you can manipulate (Scale / translate) without any effect on other views.

to change the position of the View in runtime you can use
view.setTranslationX() and view.setTranslationY();

you can also create a view programmatically with Constraints to the parent
(my personal preference)

you can use this to overlay different Views in ConstraintLayout

```
<ImageView
        android:id="imageID1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:src="yourImageStable"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        
// put your own constraints-
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="imageID2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="yourImageUnStable"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

Note: This two constraint value will draw an ImageView from the Top-Left 
corner of the Parent View (on Position x=0, y=0)

Remember: the View which you want to overlay should be written next to the other,
like here ImageID2 can overlay ImageID1.


    </ImageView>
```

Comment: please be more precise